# Misunderstanding in the following proof about ellipses.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

While studying ellipses, I've read the following proof which I can't understand.

> Taking two point $F_1$ and $F_2$,we can define an ellipse as the set
>   of points $Z$ sucht that $ZF_1+ZF_2$ has some constant value. We call
>   $F_1$ and $F_2$ the foci of the ellipse. To see that this new
>   definition of an ellipse satisfies our equation form,we apply the
>   distance formula. First we draw the axes of the ellipse and note that
>   $CD=2b$ and $AB=2a$. Now we can find the constant sum $ZF_1+ZF_2$.
>
> Letting $Z$ be $A$ we have $ZF_1+ZF_2=AF_1 +AF_2=BF_2+AF_2=AB=2a$
>   where we note that $AF_1=BF_2$.
>   [image]

Now what is unclear to me is whether $AF_1=BF_2$ is true because  of the fact that we have  $ZF_1 + ZF_2$ constant or because  the author has  a priori defined  $F_1$ and $F_2$ as equidistant.

If the first option is the true one,can you help me understanding  the why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all points $Z$, we have $ZF_1+ZF_2$ a constant.  That means that

$$
AF_1+AF_2 = BF_1+BF_2
$$
$$
AF_1+AF_1+F_1F_2 = BF_2+F_2F_1+BF_2
$$
$$
2AF_1 = 2BF_2
$$
$$
AF_1 = BF_2
$$

Comment: Thank you.I didn't see that easy fact(Couldn't the author write it all up as you did ?D:)